# What is the ValueTask equivalent of Task.CompletedTask?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, valuetask

I am implementing `IAsyncDisposable` which requires me to return a `ValueTask`, but sometimes my dispose method has nothing to do. How should I return in this case?

At the moment I'm returning `new ValueTask(Task.CompletedTask)` which seems to work but since the point of valueTasks is to avoid creating unnecessary heap objects, I'm sure there should be a simpler and more efficient way.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

All structs have a default constructor. The default constructor of [`ValueTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask) creates a completed `ValueTask`:

```
var completedValueTask = new ValueTask();
```

Or alternatively:

```
ValueTask completedValueTask = default;
```

---

**Update:** The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask#remarks) has been updated with the following note:

> An instance created with the parameterless constructor or by the `default(ValueTask)` syntax (a zero-initialized structure) represents a synchronously, successfully completed operation.

Comment: Thanks - seems quite obvious, I don't know why I didn't think of that :-)

Answer (score 24):

#### .NET 5.0:

You can use [`ValueTask.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.completedtask).